Can we use parameters and String Interpolation in typeORM in the same query?
i have an sql query in which im inserting multiple values like so
INSERT INTO form_transaction_setup(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 ,..., value19)
VALUES('${value1}', '${value2}','${value3}', '${value4}', '${value5}', ... , '${value19}')

All of these values except one are grabbed from a variety of different tables and are guaranteed to be sanitized properly. Value 5 however, comes from the client-side and can contain apostrophes, commas, and ofcourse is vulnerable to SQL Injection. I wanted to specify value 5 as a parameter in my sql query which is being built via typeORM, but it keeps giving me a syntax error where I place the question mark(?) to represent the parameter.
This is the query that I have tried
await getConnection().query(
`INSERT INTO form_transaction_setup(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 ,..., value19)
VALUES('${value1}', '${value2}','${value3}', '${value4}', ? , ... , '${value19}',[value5])`

have also tried alternatives such as ['${value5}'] or ['value5'], thinking that the problem is in the parameters. But logging the query shows value 5 being correctly passed to the database.
This is the error I get
code: 'EREQUEST',
[0]   originalError: Error: Incorrect syntax near '?'

In brief, can I use parameters and string interpolation in the same query while using typeORM, and if yes, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.
Edit: Using parameters for all the entries was my initial choice but it causes a performance delay that becomes significant when the query is called repeatedly. (Depending on the function, it may be called 100+ times as more and more data is received)

Use parameters for all of them. String interpolation should be a last resort, not a default for “sanitized” data.

Sorry I should've mentioned this in the post. I have already tried using parameters for all of them. It causes a performance delay that for a single query doesnt seem much, but this query is called repeatedly as more and more data is inserted by the function. The function goes from taking 3-5 seconds to 20+ seconds when I use parameters for all of them. Is there any other way?

String interpolation is invisible to TypeORM, it just processes the query after the variables have been substituted. You should assign the template literal to a variable so you can log it and see where the syntax error is.

@Ry- I went for your suggestion as a final resort, and was surprised to see the same error popping up regardless of using parameters. Even after passing the values as parameters, the same error is shown. The parameters are logged properly as a part of the query as well. I tried passing the parameters as :value1, :value2 and so on as well. Now it says "RequestError: Incorrect syntax near ':' . Does typeORM not allow parameters at all?

Found the solution on this page https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/881. typeORM has multiple different ways to declare variables but which one is valid depends on the underlying driver. I was using mssql and mssql requires that we declare our parameters as @0, @1... and so on. So the correct query is
`INSERT INTO form_transaction_setup(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 ,..., value19)
VALUES('${value1}', '${value2}','${value3}', '${value4}', @0 , ... , '${value19}',[value5])`

and then declaring the parameter normally as follows
await getConnection().query("our corrected query here"), [value5]

